# How do I deploy to IIS without Admin Access

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis

I am a non-admin user trying to deploy a .net core app to IIS. I have
deployed the app to a folder and need to configure IIS virtual application to point to that folder. How can I achieve this? Please bear in mind that I do not have access to open IIS Manager. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, without enough permission we couldn't modify any IIS settings. As far as I know, all the settings will inside the applicationhost.config.  I suggest you could try to access the `applicationhost.config` file. Path:`C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\`.

If you could access this path, then you could modify the settings to add the virtualDirectory  as below:

```
        <site name="TroubleshootingRelatedVitualPath" id="70" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="TroubleshootingRelatedVitualPath">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\TroubleshootingRelatedVitualPath" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8087:" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```